# Set Cmake toolchain file in build matrix in travis ci

Tags: cmake, continuous-integration, cross-compiling, travis-ci

is there any way to set cmake toolchain files as an environment variable? The background: i would like to make a travis ci matrix build for different cross-compilers we use.

Best Regards,

Comment: See the [relevant section in the docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build#Build-Matrix)

Comment: @набиячлэвэлиь i can not found how to pass toolchain file via environment

Comment: See the second example of [this section](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build#Explicity-Including-Builds). Observe and learn